# what is wrong with these Gemplus and Visa javacards?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader

I have two java card. One of them is a gemplus (with `A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00` as its card manager AID) and another one is a Visa java card (With `A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00` as its card manager AID).
as you see in these pictures I want to authenticate or reset them. but I receive `6982` APDU response [Security status not satisfied].can any body help me to handle this? is these cards locked? thank you.
[image]

Comment: if it is better to copy and paste the code instead of put a picture, please tell me :)

Comment: yes, that would certainly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6982 on INITIALIZE UPDATE typically means card locked. This is irreversible, at least without further knowledge of the card operating system.